# Replace all strings from an array of strings won't work

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

I have the following string

```php
$content = '[tab title="Tab A" content="Tab a content."][tab title="Tab B" content="Tab B content"][tab title="Tab C" content="Tab C content"]';
```

Now I want to split the content like so:

```php
$contentID = preg_split('/(\]\[)|(\]\s*\[)/', $content);
```

So far so good, now I need to check if each string of the `$contentID` array contains the `id=` part so I can add it if missing:

```php
// set a new array
$newContentID = array();
// set a unique ID
$id = 'unique';

// include an id attribute for each string part
foreach ( $contentID as $i => $tabID ) {
 $newContentID[$i] = !strpos( $tabID, 'id=' ) === true ? str_replace( '[tab', '[tab id="'.$id.'-'.$i.'"', $tabID) : $tabID;
}
```

In the end I just implode all contents into the same `$content` array.

```php
$content = implode('][',$newContentID);
```

The contents of the new `#content` goes like this:

```php
var_dump($content);

/////////////// RESULT ///////////////////
string "[tab id="unique-0" title="Tab A" content="Tab a content."][tab title="Tab B" content="Tab B content"][tab title="Tab C" content="Tab C content"]"


var_dump($contentID);

/////////////// RESULT ///////////////////

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "
[tab id="tab-a" title="Tab A" active="1" content="Tab a content""
  [1]=>
  string(13) "tab id="tab-b" title="Tab B" content="Tab B content""
  [2]=>
  string(13) "tab id="tab-c" title="Tab C" content="Tab C content."]
"
}
```

Why doesn't `foreach` do what I'm expecting it to do (to add `id` in each string part where missing)? How can I solve this?

Comment: `var_dump($contentID);` for enlightenment …

Comment: I really dont understand what your goal is.

Comment: Instead of splitting, I’d go with matching - `preg_match_all('/\[.*\]/U', $content, $contentID); $contentID = $contentID[0];` Then you can leave the rest of the code unchanged, and it doesn’t fail like the suggested workaround in the answer potentially easily could.

Comment: @04FS thanks again for your suggestion, I might have to get the issue into another forum since the value of the `content="HERE"` could also have nested tags, but I will try to change the entire functionality to avoid unwanted complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id part is not being added because the result of the `preg_split` is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(43) "[tab title="Tab A" content="Tab a content.""
  [1]=>
  string(41) "tab title="Tab B" content="Tab B content""
  [2]=>
  string(42) "tab title="Tab C" content="Tab C content"]"
}
```

This means that the `str_replace('[tab', '[tab id="'.$id.'-'.$i.'"', $tabID)` on the foreach is not going to work because for the array indexes (1, 2) there is no string `[tab` to be replaced.

A workaround is to check if `[tab` exists with the `strpos` function like this:

```
$content = '[tab title="Tab A" content="Tab a content."][tab title="Tab B" content="Tab B content"][tab title="Tab C" content="Tab C content"]';

$contentID = preg_split('/(\]\[)|(\]\s*\[)/', $content);

// set a new array
$newContentID = array();
// set a unique ID
$id = 'unique';

// include an id attribute for each string part
foreach ( $contentID as $i => $tabID ) {
 $newContentID[$i] = strpos($tabID, 'id=') === false ? addId($tabID, $id, $i) : $tabID;
}

$content = implode('][',$newContentID);

function addId($tabID, $id, $i) {
    if (strpos($tabID, '[tab') === 0) {
        return str_replace('[tab', '[tab id="'.$id.'-'.$i.'"', $tabID);
    } else if (strpos($tabID, 'tab') === 0) {
        return 'tab id="' . $id . '-' . $i . '"' . substr($tabID, 3);
    }
}
```

The result of `echo $content`:

```
[tab id="unique-0" title="Tab A" content="Tab a content."][tab id="unique-1" title="Tab B" content="Tab B content"][tab id="unique-2" title="Tab C" content="Tab C content"]
```

Comment: Ah you're so right, thank you so much for spotting the missing `[`.

Comment: That workaround is going to mess things up, if one of those parts that do not begin with [tab should contain `tab` in lowercase anywhere …

Comment: @04FS I figured that, also having the word `tab` inside the `content="HERE"` could mess things up big time, so I'm considering splitting the string by `]` and readding the `]` on each part.

Comment: @thednp that's probably a better approach